# Miner RIG does not initial all NVIDIA for mining

Tags: mining, ethminer, gpu, nvidia

I have a Ethereum RIG with 8 NVIDIA 1070 and UBUNTU 16.04 OS.
When I check my hardware with lspci command, it shows 7 NVIDIA graphic cards;
When I start ethminer (ethminer -G -F http://eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:80/0xf88f3392c3cca1890b522a6154d16703d4627fab/Rig01/hesam.es@gmail.com), it uses only 4 graphic cards.
How could I update my ethminer hardware list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using EthOSDistro.com I have been using it for over 1 & 1/2 years.
All you need to do is update your config file when you first boot with your pool and wallet address and reboot.  Once it comes back up it will start mining.  No messing about trying to configure stuff, I believe the distro was built on ubuntu also.

The reason I moved to EthOS Distro was that I was tired of always tweaking and attending to my rig while for something.

Now they run 24/7 , i often forget about them and remember to go check them and give them a rest by rebooting them.